# SQLAlchemy imperative mapping can't add entity using foreign key for another entity

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm having a few issues with SQLAlchemy imperative mappings when trying to add a new entity using the foreign key.

If I define my mapped class as:

```py
@attr.s
class Foreign:
    id = attr.ib(type=int, validator=optional(instance_of(int)), default=None)
    name = attr.ib(type=str, validator=instance_of(str), default=None)


@attr.s
class Primary:
    id = attr.ib(type=int, validator=optional(instance_of(int)), default=None)
    foreign_id = attr.ib(type=int, validator=optional(instance_of(int)), default=None)
    foreign = attr.ib(type=Foreign, validator=optional(instance_of(Foreign)), default=None)
```

When adding a new entity like:

```py
session.add(Primary(foreign_id=foreign_id))
session.commit()
```

It fails because it replaces the foreign_id with None as I guess it's expecting the foreign property to be filled instead.

These are my tables:

```py
mapper_registry = registry()

primary = Table(
    "primary",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("foreign_id", Integer, ForeignKey("foreign.id"), nullable=False),
)

foreign = Table(
    "foreign",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("name", String(20), nullable=False),
)

def configure_mappers():
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Foreign, foreign)

def configure_mappers():
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        Primary,
        primary,
        properties={
            "foreign": relationship(Foreign),
        },
    )
```

However, if I remove the `foreign` attribute from the Mapped Class it works perfectly.

How do I add a new entity using the foreign key if my mapped class has the mapping to the foreign key and the foreign class?

Answer (score 0):

From [attrs documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html):

> Try to design your classes in a way that is clean and convenient to
> use – not based on your database format. The database format can
> change anytime and you’re stuck with a bad class design that is hard
> to change. Embrace functions and classmethods as a filter between
> reality and what’s best for you to work with.

In case you absolutely need to access the ids from your Python code and / or instanciate your Primary objects both from foreign ids and objects, you could check the class instance methods and write two class methods to instanciate Primary:

- one to instanciate Primary with the foreign object instance,
- the other one to instanciate Primary using the Foreign object id as a foreign key.

---

## alternative design

As I understand it, the value of an ORM (especially in its imperative mapping flavor), is to be able to express your code without having to deal with database concepts such as id and foreign keys.

Moreover, being able to instanciate Primary or Foreign objects with a discrete id contradicts the fact that it is used as a primary key: the constraint of having a unique key is not enforced in the Python code.

The advantage of imperative mapping lies in completely decoupling the domain object from its database implementation, so you can leave SQLAlchemy deal with the ids behind the scene.

### model.py

```
import attr
from attr.validators import instance_of
from attr.validators import optional


@attr.s
class Foreign:
    name = attr.ib(type=str, validator=instance_of(str), default=None)


@attr.s
class Primary:
    name = attr.ib(type=str, validator=instance_of(str), default=None)
    foreign = attr.ib(type=Foreign, validator=optional(instance_of(Foreign)), default=None)
```

### orm.py

```
import model
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import Table


metadata = MetaData()
mapper_registry = registry()

table_primary = Table(
    "primary",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("foreign_id", Integer, ForeignKey("foreign.id"), nullable=False),
)


table_foreign = Table(
    "foreign",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("name", String(20), nullable=False),
)


def configure_mappers():
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(model.Foreign, table_foreign)

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        model.Primary,
        table_primary,
        properties={
            "foreign": relationship(model.Foreign),
        },
    )
```

### Usage

```
import orm
import model
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///my_db.db")

orm.metadata.create_all(engine)
orm.configure_mappers()
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


foreign_1 = model.Foreign(name="first foreign")
foreign_2 = model.Foreign(name="second foreign")
foreign_3 = model.Foreign(name="third foreign")
primary_a = model.Primary(name="first primary", foreign=foreign_3)
primary_b = model.Primary(name="second primary", foreign=foreign_2)
session.add_all([foreign_1, primary_a, primary_b])
session.commit()
```